# Error while creating a network for Manager , Worker node

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

There is 1 manager node ES11 & 2 worker nodes ES12, ES13

When trying to run the command on ES13:

```
sudo docker-compose -f config-certs.yml run --rm config_certs
```

Gets error: *Creating network "es-elastic" with driver "overlay"
ERROR: Cannot create a multi-host network from a worker node. Please create the network from a manager node.*

When running the same command on ES12 (other worker node), it runs fine.
Had already created an overlay network with ES11 as manager node.

---

I see ES11 & ES12 are both manager nodes but not ES13. When trying to run the below command on ES11 to make ES13 a manager node, i get another error as below:

```
Command: sudo docker node promote ES13
```

Error response from daemon: node ES13 is ambiguous (2 matche                                                                                                             s found)

Comment: Please include the relevant docker compose files and/or Dockerfiles.

Comment: Elasticsearch doesn't have work or manager nodes, so it's not entirely clear what you mean here sorry

Comment: Thanks @NickK9 and warkolm . was able to resolve it by removing the ambiguity from ES13 and afterwards promoting the node to manager node

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve it by removing the ambiguity from ES13 and afterwards promoting the node to manager node